# Does 3D Analyze really work?

Tags: 3d-analyze

I have heard that 3D Analyze lets you play high end games on your PC. I have tried it once with Prince of Persia: Sands of Time, but it did not help me there.

Does it really work or its just a hoax?

If it does indeed work, can anybody provide a link to instructions on how to make it work?

Comment: From a brief look [here](http://www.techenclave.com/applications/3d-analyze-v2-26-graphics-card-91070.html) it seems you could only benefit from 3D Analayze if you have a video card that doesn't already support transform and lighting.  Listing the hardware specifications of your PC could help us answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only useful for very old (older than ~2003) video cards without Hardware Transform and Lighting units. It emulates this functionality to allow software requiring this feature to work on these graphics cards, and in a few cases to allow certain software to run faster.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it does bro i have run many games using this it also speeds up games if they already work for ex nfsmw the first one i didnt have many graphics options before 3danalyze after i used it it cleared so much lag and opened more options like visual treatment etcc